# Can a PWA be embedded in a Flutter app for both Android and iOS?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, progressive-web-apps

It looks like you can embed PWA into Flutter apps [on Android](https://developers.google.com/web/android/trusted-web-activity). Is it possible to do something similar with iOS?

I'm trying to find out if I can have a Flutter app with an extra tab that seamlessly embeds a PWA on both Android and iOS, so that when you download the mobile app from an app store you get all the functionality of an existing PWA inside the larger mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Google Play, but Apple Mobile store rejects apps that are substantially a wrapper around a single website.  I presume this would include bundling a PWA.